# If every $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ has a neighbourhood whose intersection with the set $A$ is closed, then $A$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

How would I go about proving this statement?

Denoting the each neighbourhood by $V_{x}$, I have tried to use the following facts:

$$
\bigcup V_{x} = \mathbb{R}^{n}
$$

and thus

$$
\bigcup \left(A \cap V_{x}\right) = A \cap \left(\bigcup V_{x}\right) = A
$$

But the left hand side is an infinite union of closed sets and so this path of thinking does not seem that useful.

Comment: maybe $V_x$ makes more sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be a limit point of $A$. Then there is a sequence $x_n \in A$ such that $\lim x_n = x$. By assumption there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U \cap A$ is closed. Then there is an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for $n \geq N $, $x_n \in A \cap U$. So $x$ is a limit point of $U \cap A$. So $x \in U\cap A$(since it's closed). Now $x \in A\cap U \subset A$. So $A$ is closed.